# nginx location regex setting to return 404 only on specified url

Tags: regex, wordpress, nginx, pagination, pcre

I have wordpress pagination and I want that the *www.site.com/page/1235x* returning me a 404.

At the same time I don't want to disable the pagination for the entire site because I use it with other url, like */categories/page/2* or */page/2/?s=search-item* .

So, I thought I need to write a nginx regex that match only a piece of the url.

I have three example url:

**1. www.site.com/page/2/ 

2. www.site.com/page/2  

3. www.site.com/page/2/?s=term-of-search**

For the first and second I want to return 404 with something like this: 
**location ~* ^/page/\d+/?$ { return 404; }** 
And this matched.

For the third I don't want nothing, but that normally goes the search result.

Unfortunately, my test always select the part  *www.site.com/page/2/* returning 404.
I've done a lot of test with ngnix regex, also with order of them,
but I can't find a solution to this.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: The regex will only match the path, not the query string. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/811912/can-nginx-location-blocks-match-a-url-query-string

Comment: Ok, but there is a way to invert the regex? I mean, I don't need to return anything if in the url there is a query string, instead I need to return 404 if there isn't. Something like if (not query string and match the url...) do something..

Comment: Sure. Look at the linked post. It checks for different contents of `$query_string`. Make one such check for empty string.